# Plots do not show with bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

i am trying to export a report as HTML using Bokeh with python. Can anybody tell me, why my code is not working? I tried to print a simple Div and succeeded, but as soon as i include plots, the browser still opens, but nothing is visible. Is it not possible to inherit Figure?

I reduced it to the relevant parts:

```
def export_html(self):
    plots=[]
    plots.append(PlotObject(self.plot_attributes[4]))
    VisuLog(plots)


from bokeh.plotting import Figure, show, output_file

class VisuLog():
    def __init__(self,plots):
       self.plots = plots
       filename="Report_"
       output_file("visu_out\\"+ filename + ".html", title=filename)
       show(self.plots)  # open a browser

class PlotObject(Figure):
   def __init__(self,plot_attributes):
       super(PlotObject, self).__init__()
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```py
__subtype__ = 'PlotObject'
__view_model__ = 'Plot'
```

to the body of the `PlotObject` class.

But I would advise against extending Bokeh objects unless you want to provide some UI behavior by writing custom JavaScript/TypeScript implementation.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, but i get the following warning: Apparently the PlotObject inherits those from the Figure class

Warning: Duplicate __view_model__ or __subtype__ declaration of 'Figure' for class PlotObject.  Previous definition: <class 'bokeh.plotting.figure.Figure'>

Comment: No idea - works for me on Bokeh 2.0.2. But as I said, I strongly recommend against doing that in the first place since it's an implementation detail and not a public API.

Comment: Okey, thanks updating from 2.0.0 to 2.0.2 indeed helped.